# Optimize performance with multiple calls to Regex.IsMatch on large text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long text (50-60 KB) and I need to run several regular expressions against it (about 100 rules in total). However, this is so slow that it essentially doesn't work.

All I have done is created a loop around the rules where each rule does a `Regex.IsMatch()`.

Is there a way to optimize this?

**UPDATE**

Sample code of what each rule is doing:

```
public class SomeRegexInterceptor : ValidatorBase
    {
        private readonly Regex _rgx = new Regex("some regex", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline); 

        public override void Intercept(string html, ValidationResultCollection collection)
        {
            if (!_rgx.IsMatch(html)) return;

            /* do something irrelevant here */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you initialise the Regex outside of the loop with the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag. Also remove as much as possible from the loop. If you can work line by line, try doing that instead of searching one giant 50-60KB string.

Comment: @AeroX  - I wasn't you can check the sample code for reference

Comment: How many times and where do you create this class instances? It is not static and the regex is initialized right at the instance creation. That is inefficient.

Comment: It's also quite (much more?) likely that the regexes themselves can/need to be optimized.  Time each regex match to see if there are regexes that take exceptionally long to match (or to fail to match). Problems like these often result from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important thing about the usage of Regex replacements is how and where you declare your Regex. **Never initialize a Regex object inside a loop.**

Create a static class and add `public static readonly` Regex fields with `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag set.

Then, use them wherever you need using something like `MyRegexClass.LeadingWhitespace.Replace(str, string.Empty)`.

Note that if you need to use `Regex.Replace`, you do not need to check if there is a match with `Regex.IsMatch` before.

Read and follow the recommendations outlined at [*Best Practices for Regular Expressions in the .NET Framework*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx), namely:

- [Consider the Input Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx#InputSource)
- [Handle Object Instantiation Appropriately](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx#ObjectInstantiation)
- [Take Charge of Backtracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx#Backtracking)
- [Use Time-out Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx#Timeouts)
- [Capture Only When Necessary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx#Capture)

Also, consider processing the file line by line, and avoid regular expressions wherever you can do without them.

Comment: Hey - Please check the sample code provided. I don't think I am doing anything crazy.

Comment: Perhaps, parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea? ;-) I am sure the problem is with some regex that causes huge backtracking. Debug your expressions and check where execution stumbles. Fix the pattern. Repeat. Pay special attention to `.*`.

Comment: That .* was the culprit. Thanks

Comment: I'd like to add that I doubt significant issues would arise from constructing a Regex within a loop or even not using `RegexOptions.Compiled` as C# caches Regexes with `Regex.CacheSize` so as long as you have a relatively small amount of Regexes, it should be relatively about the same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/compilation-and-reuse-in-regular-expressions

Comment: @derekantrican Actually, with the latest developments, .NET regex has become much more stable and less prone to issues like catastrophic backtracking, etc. This 6-year old answer reflects the best practices we followed at my former work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine your rules into one rule?  For example: if you are doing a regex for "aaa" and then one for "bbb", combining into "aaa|bbb" improves performance greatly ( rather than running two separate regexes ).  I have programatically combined a large number of regexes in this way before and it makes a huge performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

### Combining Expressions

If you have the ability to do work prior to running your rules, you could combine the regexes with `|` and do the search in one pass. Then in your rule you don't check for a match anonymously like you were, but by the name of the group. For example

```
>((?<Ex1>expression1)|(?<Ex2>expression2)|(?<Ex3>expression3))
```

So the rule that cares about group `Ex1`, it checks that group. The rule that cares about `Ex2` checks `Ex2` and so on.

Additionally, you could possibly analyze the set of regexes and optimize them somehow. That would be quite a programmatic feat unless you're doing something simple like eliminating duplicates.

### Caching, Cache Size

One other idea is to cache up and compile all the regexes once somewhere, *and* change the size of `Regex.CacheSize` to see if it helps. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize(v=vs.110).aspx) states the default value is **15**, but you're over that.

### More Info

The comments about instantiating and compiling the expression once, not looeven that big one there, are valid. There are additional recommendations [from MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx).