# Is there a fast extraction of specific value located inside tags in a slice from a list of strings possible?

Tags: c#, regex, list, optimization

I'm using a 2 step regex to extract the value of the first occurance of a specific marker inside a list of strings:

```
Regex regexComplete = new Regex(
    @"MyNumberMarker"
    + @"[\d]+"
    + @"[\s]+Endmarker"
);

Regex regexOnlyNumber = new Regex(
    @"MyNumberMarker"
    + @"[\d]+"
);

int indexmyNumber = eintraegeListe.FindIndex(
    5,
    10000,
    x => regexComplete.IsMatch(x)
);

if (indexmyNumber >= 0)
{
    int myNumber = 0;
    string myNumberString = regexOnlyNumber.Match(regexComplete.Match(eintraegeListe[indexmyNumber]).Value).Value;
    myNumberString = myNumberString.Replace("MyNumberMarker", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Trim();

    if (Int32.TryParse(myNumberString, out myNumber))
    {
        return myNumber;
    }
}
```

As one can see the value I really want is located between "MyNumberMarker" and "Endmarker". It is in a specific part of the list which I search through with the findIndex command. Then I use regex to extract the complete value + tag and reduce it to "just" the begin tag and the value and then manually cut away the begin tag and all could be white spaces (including \n and \r).

Now this works quite fine as intended but if I do this a couple of thousand times it is quite slow in the end. Thus my question.
Is there any better (faster) way to do this?

*As a note: eintraegeListe can have between 100 and 30000 entries.*

For example if I have the following small list:

```
[0]This is a test
[1]22.09.2015 01:00:00
[2]Until 22.09.2015 03:00:00
[3]................................
[4]................................
[5]........ TESTDATA
[6]...............................
[7]................................
[8]MyNumberMarker519 Endmarker
[9]This is a small
[10]Slice of Test data with
[11]520 - 1 as data.
```

I would expect **519** to be returned.

Comment: An example of raw input and desired output would help.

Comment: Added a very basic example with only 11 entries.

Comment: Have you tried using the options `RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled` when you create your regex? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where do you initialize Regex objects? If inside the loops, then it will be slow. Besides, use just one regex: `Regex regexComplete = new Regex(@"MyNumberMarker(?<number>\d+)\s+Endmarker");`, and then you will have access to it via `rx.Match(input).Groups["number"].Value`.

Comment: Also, please see [my answer on optimizing regex in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432630/optimize-performance-with-multiple-calls-to-regex-ismatch-on-large-text/31432829#31432829).

Comment: The objects themselves are instantiated with the singleline and compiled options and in the main class itself (thus outside the loop). Tried it inside the loop (no real difference in terms of time).

Comment: @stribizhev do I understand the example there correct that that would make the replace obsolete? So to say that number is the name of the group for the following statement. In this case the \d+  ?

Comment: Yes, that would reduce your code to 1 regex object only, and 1 match operation after which you will be able to get your number straight from the match object.

Comment: so the ismatch first and then the match (and both using the group aka the same regex statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually merge the two regexps into 1 containing a *capturing group* that will let you access the sequence of digits directly via the group name (here, `"number"`).

```
Regex regexComplete = new Regex(@"MyNumberMarker(?<number>\d+)\s+Endmarker");
```

Now, you do not need `regexOnlyNumber`.

Then, you can add a non-regex condition as in the other answer.  Maybe this will be enough (the `.Contains` will be executed first and the whole expression should evaluate to false if the first condition is not met - see ["short-circuit" evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.71).aspx)) (`IndexOf` with `StringComparison.Ordinal` looks preferable anyway):

```
int indexmyNumber = eintraegeListe.FindIndex(5, 10000, x => x.Contains("MyNumberMarker") && regexComplete.IsMatch(x));
```

And then:

```
if (indexmyNumber >= 0)
{
    int myNumber = 0;
    string myNumberString = regexComplete.Match(eintraegeListe[indexmyNumber]).Groups["number"].Value;
    if (Int32.TryParse(myNumberString, out myNumber))
    {
        return myNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it is now much clearer. Please let me know if you need more assistance with this issue.

Comment: Yepp works. The difference between before and after the changes is: 1 to 10 (in terms of time needed).  So it works almost as fast as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are returning a single item, the performance of code past `FindIndex` is irrelevant: it is executed only once, and it takes a single string, so it should complete in microseconds on any modern hardware.

The code that takes the bulk of CPU is in `x => regexComplete.IsMatch(x)` call. You can tell that this code is returning `false` most of the time, because the loop is over the first time it returns `true`.

This means that you should be optimizing for the negative case, i.e. returning `false` as soon as you can. One way to achieve this would be to look for `"MyNumberMarker"` before employing regex. If there is no marker, return `false` right away; otherwise, fall back on using the regex, and start from the position where you found the marker:

```
int indexmyNumber = eintraegeListe.FindIndex(
    5,
    10000,
    x => {
        // Scan the string for the marker in non-regex mode
        int pos = x.IndexOf("MyNumberMarker", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        // If the marker is not there, do not bother with regex, and return false
        return pos < 0
             ? false
             // Only if the marker is there, check the match with regex.
             : regexComplete.IsMatch(x, pos);
    }
);
```