# RegEx best practices in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I came across writing Regular Expressions against user input in a C# console application, here are a couple of questions:

- When a RegEx becomes pretty long like below, is it smart to keep where it is in the code? Or put it with my other constants in their own class? Or even smarter to just not use it and do it some other way?

  ```
  Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*");
  ```
- How does RegEx affect the behavior/load of my application and what more do I have to consider when using RegEx?

Comment: if you are using it only once then no problem to put it behind code. but if you are using it multiple times then you should create only one regex.

Comment: Do you need to capture something with all your capture groups?

Comment: IMHO the answer to question #1 will be opinion based and the answer to question #2 depends on how you are using the regex - and your question gives us no specifics to work with

Comment: Without studying your regex any further, the first view on constructs like `)*)*` [looks explosive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Generally a long pattern must not be a bad pattern. What input should be matched by your regex?

Comment: I would write them as a static field.

Comment: Here is [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31432829/3832970) that IMHO answers most of what you ask.

Comment: The method containing the RegEx fires up after a user puts his username in the console application, and before the username is used to request the authentication, I need to check that the username is written in a format that doesn't cause the authentication request to crash.

Comment: @bobblebubble: it looks only, but it is not here. Something like `(a*)*` may become explosive only if it is followed by a constraint like in `(a*)*b`

Comment: @I'mdroid: No need I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use Regular Expressions. You should however look out for the performance implications if used incorrectly. If you are using it frequently, you should look at using Compiled Regular Expressions.

For further reading on the performance & best practices there is a nice MSDN article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx

Comment: The article doesn't exist anymore, here is the archive.org url: https://web.archive.org/web/20190121072532/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects-ron-petrusha