# Best practise for parsing trace data

Tags: c#, regex, multithreading, performance

My app is parsing continuously incoming traces.
I have precompiled regular expressions in an external library. 
Reading and analysing the incomming data is done in the following function, which is running in a worker thread.

For demonstration purposes I have stripped down the code. Currently it uses 30 different regex which are checked sequentially.

```
    private void Filter()
    {
        Regex rgx_1 = new RegEx_1();
        Regex rgx_2 = new RegEx_2();
        ...
        Regex rgx_N = new RegEx_N();

        uint index = 0;
        while (!FilterThread.CancellationPending)
        {
            BufferLength = (int)Source.GetItemCount() - 1;
            if (index <= BufferLength)
            {
                item = (ColorItem)Source.GetItem(index);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    tracecontend = item.GetItemSummary();
                    if (rgx_1.IsMatch(tracecontend))
                    {
                        current_trace = new TraceLine(index, tracecontend, GROUP_1);
                    }
                    else if (rgx_2.IsMatch(tracecontend))
                    {
                        current_trace = new TraceLine(index, tracecontend, GROUP_2);
                    }
                    else if (rgx_3.IsMatch(tracecontend))
                    {
                        current_trace = new TraceLine(index, tracecontend, GROUP_3);
                    }
                    ...
                    else if (rgx_N.IsMatch(tracecontend))
                    {
                        current_trace = new TraceLine(index, tracecontend, GROUP_N);
                    }
                    listBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new AddTraceDelegate(AddTrace), current_trace);
                }
                index++;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

By this approach I can handle up to 500 traces per seconds, which is sufficient for real time tracing. But reading files containing up to 2.000.000 traces still takes quite a long time.

Do you have any idea how to speed up the execution and to in crease the throughput?

Is anyone having best practises for such a case?

EDIT:
here is an example of a regex

```
           compilationList.Add(new RegexCompilationInfo(@"SomeTextToFilterFor(.*?)",
                   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant,
                   "RegEx_1",
                   "Utilities.RegularExpressions",
                   true));
          RegexCompilationInfo[] compilationArray = new RegexCompilationInfo[compilationList.Count];
          AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName("RegexLib, Version=1.0.0.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
          compilationList.CopyTo(compilationArray);
          Regex.CompileToAssembly(compilationArray, assemName);
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [*Optimize performance with multiple calls to Regex.IsMatch on large text*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432630/optimize-performance-with-multiple-calls-to-regex-ismatch-on-large-text/31432829#31432829). The point is: 1) are you using effecient regexes? 2) are you declaring them as private static readonly fields with `RegexOptions.Compiled`? (I guess no by looking at the question).

Comment: What's the average length of `tracecontend` ?

Comment: I believe you have regex patterns with `.*` and `.*?`. Review them for effeciency. If you parse HTML with regexps, reconsider the approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have edited the question and added a RegEx for example.  I'm using as less as possible .* or .*? only in some of them I'm having (.*?) or (/d+) in order to get some values for further handling

Comment: @Thomas A line is approx. 100 bytes long

Comment: @thowa any change that `GROUP_X` appears more often than `GROUP_Y` ?

Comment: Do you understand what `@"SomeTextToFilterFor(.*?)"` matches? It matches `SomeTextToFilterFor` - and nothing else. If all of those regexps look like this, you really need to review them.

Comment: @Thomas no you can't predict, which group appears more often. Of course, I would order the loop that way to leave at earlierst time.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex filters for lines contaning `@"SomeTextToFilterFor(.*?)"` and returning the contend followed by it. e.g. `SomeTextToFilterFor_DataXX` or `SomeTextToFilterFor_DataXY`

Comment: [Oh, are you sure?](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=SomeTextToFilterFor(.*%3f)&i=SomeTextToFilterFor+and+please+match+this...+Why+not%3f!) The lazy dot matching patterns with `*?` at the end of the pattern will never match anything. And if there is a newline, the `.` will not match it, it needs a Singleline modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right, this pattern matches nothing. Thanks for pointing this out. **I need to review the regex'es**

Answer (score 1):

There is the numbers of ways you can improve speed.

**Combine your regexes if possible**

Regex is state machine that has possibility to backtrace but will try to do all work in one go. One go is bettern than many match calls.

For example this:

```
aaaaaab | aaaaaac
```

is slower than this:

```
aaaaaa(b|c)
```

and of course it is much slower if you run them separately.

**Optimize regex itself**

You can use *RegexBuddy* for those purposes. Simply type some pattern and source and you will see all backtraces and time-consuming part of regex. You can change structure of pattern or just add *if-clause* in your regex to block backtraces.

For example you can filter cases when you know certain part of pattern can match only on some ocasions:

```
(?(?=/*fast to check condition*/)/*complex regex here*/|/*simple regex here*/)
```

**Precompile patterns** throw them out of local scope into global scope (make them static) and add *RegexOptions.Compiled* option.

Comment: Correct: too broad answer for a too broad question.

Comment: Combining the RegExes does not work, because the actual content is quiet different and I want to link each match to a certain group.