# Special signs with Regex Replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace string with regex but I can't replace regex special signs - I just want to regex read `^` etc as a normal string not as a special sign.
I tried `\\` but it's still not working.

```
public static string ReplaceXmlEntity(string source)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) return source;
    var xmlEntityReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        // Find all the original spaces and replace with a space
        // and placemarker for the space
        {" ", " ^"},
        {" \\^ \\^", " ^"},
        // Find all the double quotes and replace with placemarker 
        {"''", " ~ "},
        // Add extra spaces around key values so they can be isolated in
        // into their own array slots
        {",", " , "},
        {"'", " ' " },
        {"'('", " ( " },
        {"')'", " ) " },
        // Replace all the special characters and extra spaces
        {"\n", " 0x000A " },
        {"\r", " 0x000D " },
        {"\t", " 0x0009 " },
        {"\v", " 0x000B " },
    };
    return Regex.Replace(source, string.Join("|", xmlEntityReplacements.Keys
        .Select(k => k.ToString()).ToArray()), m => xmlEntityReplacements[m.Value]);
}
```

Comment: You need not add backslash to the keys, instead, use `Regex.Escape` to escape them dynamically, something like `xmlEntityReplacements.Keys.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k.ToString()))` (not even sure you need `.ToString()` here)

Comment: Ok thanks i changed to ```return Regex.Replace(source, string.Join("|", xmlEntityReplacements.Keys.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k.ToString())).ToArray()), m => xmlEntityReplacements[m.Value]);
``` and now its working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you escape the special characters in the dictionary keys, you will no longer be able to access them unless you unescape the matches, but that might lead to other issues. That means you should instead use `Regex.Escape` to escape each dictionary key individually:

```
xmlEntityReplacements.Keys.Select(k => Regex.Escape(k.ToString()))
```

You do not need `.ToArray`, [`string.Join` accepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) an `IEnumerable`, too.

Comment: Btw i have a question/ with one is faster to use regex as i do up or just to use string.replace() many times?

Comment: @ps-create You may test it in your own environment on the actual data. If you [follow the guidelines on regex usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31432829/3832970), the regex solution may be as fast as can be since the string will only get processed once.